# Partition and Clustering key selection for best performance

Tags: cassandra

I am going to design a Cassandra cluster for telecom domein with 7 nodes and data volume 30 TB on 45 days retention.Application Layer will generate unique transaction id for each transaction which is a combination of mobile number and date-time.Customer can ask for all details of a specific mobile number for a particular day/range of dates,All transactions for a day and from these details,they can go for all details extraction for a particular Transaction id.

1> Will it be a good idea to create a single table keeping Transaction id as Primary key and other details as non key column.It may need 22*10^9 unique partition.Any practical example of so large number of partitions? secondary index needed for 1st 2 types of quesries

2> Will it be a better idea to create different tables.One with Primary key (mobile number as partition and date as cluster) and other with transaction id as primary key.Storage requirements will be more.

3> Materialised view would help here?

kindly suggest any other better idea for best performance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I don't quite understand what question you're asking. Please help me and others understand by updating the title of your post with an actual question. Thanks for being a part of the community! 

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm specifically requesting you to update the title of your post with an actual question. Cheers!

Comment: My design will have number of columns including Transaction id(unique value) and mobile number(Unique value). However a mobile number can be related with multiple transaction id(say for recharge,disconnection) but a transaction id will always be associated with a single mobile number.Which column I should choose for Partition key.Should it be transaction id ? which will cause number of partitions more OR it would be Mobile number with transaction id as clustering key so that number of partition will be lesser.client plans to search data with Transaction id.Kindly suggest ideas.Edited title.